# SQL Server pagination with page breaks

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, sql-server-2012

I would like to find the fastest way (to treat thousands of lines) to do the following query :

I have an SQL Server Table named “Flights”. This is the structure of the table :

- ID : identity of the line
- FlightDate : Date of line
- IsLastLineOfPage : a bit equal to 1 if the line is the last of a page
- ID_User : Link with another User Table

I would like to find a very fast query to SELECT all the columns, ordered by Date and ID, with two new columns named “RowNumber” and “PageNumber”. It’s like a pagination, with 5 lines per pages. If the value of IsLastLineOfPage = 1, then even if the page is not full the next line “PageNumber” must be incremented, and “RowNumber” reset to 1. For example result of the Query WHERE ID_User=5 :

Link here :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyZh6.png

I have no idea to do this… thank you !

Comment: Set up a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), post, and let us play with it?

Comment: Aside: Placing sample data and results in tabular form in the question is preferable to linking to externals images.

Comment: What version of SQL Server.

Comment: Here is the fiddle. I added many lines to the table but it seems to delete automatically each line after creating (SELECT * give 0 result)... sorry this is the first time I use this. The name of Table and row are not the same but that's the same logic : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/822ed/25

Comment: I use SQL SERVER 2012

Answer (score 0):

Since the result set is ordered, chances are it'll never be really fast. One way to make sure things stay as quick as possible is to ensure that as few rows as possible have the exact same date. Adding an index to the column used for ordering **might** help as well. To get the results (depending on the language/SQL driver you're using), you're best off using a result set cursor. Cursors gather up the results on the server but only sends them back to the client one page at a time. You can usually specify the page size. How this is done is language and driver specific, though.